# ZXing: Scanning Barcode with UPC + 5 Supplemental

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, zxing

I'm trying to scan barcode as shown below using the ZXing library.
[image: Barcode Image]
<sub>(source: [minus.com](http://i.minus.com/ih2b9lavDxOSP.png))</sub>

```
// start scanning
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "ONE_D_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

If I replace `"ONE_D_MODE"` with `"TWO_D_MODE"`, the app can successfully detect both barcodes; but the value of `result` won't change (still 051488005995).

```
// onActivityResult
if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    String result = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
```

Is there any way to get both barcode value 051488005995 and 50115?

Any other way to obtain the isbn (0142501158) above the barcodes without getting the supplemental +5 barcode (50115) would also be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`ONE_D_MODE` will work for you. You probably really want `PRODUCT_MODE`. There is no such thing as `TWO_D_MODE`. By setting this it just scans all default formats.

It is not scanning both barcodes. It is just scanning the product code. So I'm not sure what you mean about getting just the product code: that's what you already have. I assume you want both.

`MultipleBarcodeReader` is not quite for this situation as no part of the library scans for the UPC/EAN supplement by itself. It is scanned for as an extension to UPC and EAN codes only.

It will already scan for some types of extension barcode in `UPCEANExtensionSupport`. It doesn't give you back the raw values but rather tries to parse out metadata and returns that in result metadata. If that's what you really want, it already does this. Otherwise you have to modify the code.

If it reads the UPC/EAN code but can't find an extension code, it will not fail the scan, and will only return the primary code. If you want it to only return if both are found, again you'd have to change your copy of the core library.

Comment: Could you give me an example or a link about how to use `UPCEANExtensionSupport`? Before posting this question I was looking for `UPCEANReader` example, but found nothing helpful either. Really thanks for your help! (Still trying how to use ZXing directly...)

Comment: Have you actually looked at the source code? Just search for usages of this class, it's quite obvious.

Comment: Yeah, but haven't understand how it works... For example using `MultiFormatUPCEANReader` instead of `MultiFormatReader` in `DecodeHandler`?

Answer (score 1):

FYI you can scan UPC 12+5 codes via Intent/zxing. The only catch is that you have to force the +5, so you can't scan normal barcodes.

From my thread with @srowen: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/217#issuecomment-54818496

Passed the hint as an extra to the Intent, inside IntentIntegrator=>initiateScan (I'll have to make an overriden method to make this optional later):

```
// Force 5 digit extension
intentScan.putExtra("ALLOWED_EAN_EXTENSIONS", new int[] {5});
```

I confirmed it was recognized from my Android logcat:

```
DecodeHintManager﹕ Hints from the Intent: {ALLOWED_EAN_EXTENSIONS=[I@42a38540}
```

Retrieved extension values in my scan result:

```
String extension = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_UPC_EAN_EXTENSION");
```

Now I got some UPC 12+5 :)

```
Content:079808007955, Format:UPC_A, Extension: 74700
```

Comment: This worked 99% of what I was trying to do, but what I really need is for it to keep scanning until it finds an extension. Sometimes xzing just grabs the first product portion of the code and doesn't even read the extension portion.  Did you run into that problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible using zxing via an Intent.

However, you can embed ZXing in your code directly (by adding the ZXing source to your code directory). Then you are able to use the `com.google.zxing.MultipleBarcodeReader`. The function `decodeMultiple()` returns an array of barcodes which then can be processed further.

---

A small example:

```
// data: YUV camera preview; width/height: preview size
Result[] decode(byte[] data, int width, int height) {
    PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(data, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
    MultipleBarcodeReader reader = new MultipleBarcodeReader(new MultiFormatOneDReader(null));
    return reader.decodeMultiple(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: You can most certainly use the library by Intent: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent. However I don't think I wrote it to return the 'raw' supplemental info contained in the +5 barcode this way. You do need to use the source directly, but `MultipleBarcodeReader` will not work.

Comment: @SeanOwen Could you please look into it. How do i prepare a batch statement to store the whole RDD to database. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462803/prepare-batch-statement-to-store-all-the-rdd-to-mysql-generated-from-spark-strea`